# Cant connect to SQL Database but it works in Excel

Tags: c++, sql, excel

Im trying to Connect to a SQL-Server in C++, using User/PW Auth and not windows auth.

First, when i try to connect to the same Server in Excel (also adding user/pw there) it first asks me for a not secure connection, but manages to connect.

Now when i want to connect to the same Server with c++, it gives me following errors:

```
Could not connect to SQL Server
        SqlState: 28000
        Code: 18456
        Msg: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\user'.
```

So im really sure whats wrong.

The Rest of the Code looks like this. Alloc Handles

```
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlEnvHandle)) {
    std::cout << "Error in SQLAllocHandle of sqlEnvHandle" << std::endl;
    return false;
}
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0)) {
    std::cout << "Error in SQLSetEnvAttr of sqlEnvHandle" << std::endl;
    return false;
}
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlEnvHandle, &sqlConnHandle)) {
    std::cout << "Error in SQLAllocHandle of sqlConnHandle" << std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

The ConnectionString

```
std::wstring ConnectionString = L"DRIVER=" + DriverName + L";SERVER=" + ServerName + L", " + ServerPort + L";DATABASE=" + DatabaseName + L";UID=" + LoginUser + L";PWD=" + LoginPassword + L";";
```

and the SQLDriverConnect itself, witch fails with SQL_ERROR

```
SQLDriverConnect(sqlConnHandle,
        NULL,
        (SQLWCHAR*)ConnectionString.c_str(),
        SQL_NTS,
        retconstring,
        1024,
        NULL,
        SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)
```

I hope someone cal help me/tell me why Excel manages a Connection but im Failing in C++?

Comment: try to cout `ConnectionString` to shell before executing..

Comment: @mlwn the connectionstring looks like this if printed ConnectionString: DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=servername, 1433;DATABASE=dbname;UID=user\domain;PWD=mypass;

Comment: Usually, 1433 needs a `PORT=` argument. And please post the working connection string in Excel.

Comment: @Parfait how do i find the connection string that excel uses? since in excel im just clicking on add connectin -> sql